# 2007 honda civic trunk screw & peg wont come out

Tags: honda, electrical, civic, tail-lights

I recently discovered that I had no license plate lights so I immediately went to the auto part store and picked some bulbs up. Only to find that I can only replace one side because one of the screws just spins. The screw goes into a rubber peg that is split at the end - designed to open up once the screw is all the way in (to hold peg & screw in place)

We tried pliers and we tried prying it out with flat-head screwdrivers but we've pulled down on the carpeting there that now it barely touches the trunk :(

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any pictures of the issue? Would help tremendously.

Comment: At this point you should just drill the screw head and try to extract the rest of the screw body. Though if you can see the plastic receptacle you could always cut it and buy a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a knife or an ice pick to get between the body of the plug and the head of the center pin/screw.  You should be able to pry the screw part out.  It is sometimes necessary to cut the entire head off with a knife or wire cutters.

You can find replacement plugs either in the HELP! section at most auto parts stores or online at a Honda parts site, or amazon.